# scraping a table from a website not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from a sports website but unfortunately python can't **scrape** the table though there is a table there. I am new at this field so what should i do?
The link of the website
https://www.teapuesto.pe/sport/daily-matches

Comment: It looks as if the data is loaded dynamically using JavaScript, which means it's not going to be visible when you request the page source using Python. Your options are typically (a) see if you directly fetch whatever URL the javascript is fetching, or (b) use a browser automation tool like Selenium so that you have access to dynamic content.

Comment: how i can do that using selenium

Comment: There are plenty of resources on this site as well as on the broader Internet on how to accomplish this with Selenium or a similar framework. Please do some research and make an attempt at writing your solution. If you run into any issues, you can edit your question to include all pertinent details and a succinct explanation as to why your code doesn't meet your requirements. [ask]

Comment: Yes, Thank you for sharing. I am actually struggling to solve this the full day. But couldn't got any proper solution yet. Used selenium also but getting error in the end

Answer (score 2):

Actually, data is generating dynamically by javascript from api calls json response. Here is the working example:

Code:

```
#https://www.teapuesto.pe/sport/daily-matches

import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


body = {"timezone":"America/Lima","platform":"desktop","ref":"/daily-events","auth":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjowLCJ1c2VyX3R5cGUiOjAsIm1hY2hpbmVfaWQiOjAsImlwIjoiIiwicm5kX2tleSI6IiIsInVzZXJfdGltZW91dCI6MH0.xZ-p4NlhSRUB_UoIFQNILsSbYnpsF-ubCcNaKwVvzEY","language_id":3,"app_version":"2.14.07","version":"v2"}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }


api_url = "https://api.teapuesto.pe/api/v2/daily-events/"

r = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
response = r.json()['data']['sports'][0]['events']['2021-10-04']
for resp in response:
  
    print(resp['away'])
```

Output:

```
FC Zenit-2 San Petersburgo
Leixoes SC
Bangladés
FC Orenburg-2
FK Kolomna
FC Tuapse
Swansea City
Beijing Sport University FC
FC Olymp-Dolgoprudny-2     
Leningradets
Baltika-Bfu Kaliningrad    
Arsenal-2 Tula
Sheffield Wednesday 2      
Halide Edip Adivarspor     
Luki-Energiya V.luki       
Dar AL Dawa
Kfarsoum
Dynamo-2 Moscow
Salut Belgorod
Peresvet Podolsk
Rodina Moscow
Cruzeiro MG
AZ Picerno
Charlton Athletic
PFC Minyor Pernik
FC Kazanka Moscow
CF Belenenses
Cobresal
FC Saransk
AL Salt
FC Murom
Torpedo Vladimir
Dinamo Brjansk
FC Sokol Saratov
AL Akhdood
Al Wehda
FK Borac Banja Luka
Sri Lanka
Maccabi Achi Nazareth FC
Hapoel Ra`anana FC
Sektzia Ness Ziona FC
Sarpsborg 08 2
SK Brann 2
Ntnui
Notodden FK
GKS Jastrzemb
Brodd
IF Karlstad Fotbollutveckling
Mjoendalen 2
Skeid Fotball
Eidsvold TF
FC Santa Lucia Cotzumalguapa
Esbjerg FB
Vasalunds IF
IK Brage
Magdeburgo
AL Adalh FC
KV Oostende
KAS Eupen
FC Academica Clinceni
Jeugd Royal Excelsior Virton
Jeugd Union Saint Gilloise
Jeugd Lommel Sk
Oud-Heverlee Leuven
Corinthians SP
Reading FC
General Lamadrid
Argentino de Merlo
Nyiregyhaza Spartacus FC
CA Defensores de Belgrano
CDM Leandro N. Alem
CA Atlanta
Waasland Beveren
Rwd Molenbeek Youth
Crusaders FC
Albion FC
Juve Stabia
Annecy FC
Rubio Nu
Puerto Montt
Girona FC
CR Vasco da Gama RJ
CD Trofense
Llaneros FC
San Martín de Tucumán
Defensa y Justicia
CA Atenas de San Carlos
Club Necaxa
Sp. San Lorenzo
Clube Do Remo PA
Colón Santa Fe
Central Espanol FC
Club America
CF Monterrey
Delfin SC
Huachipato
Almirante Brown
Club Tijuana de Caliente
Fc Juarez

(scrapyEnv) F:\stackOverflow_answer\json_dynamic>python soccer_table.py
Dinamo St Petersburg
Rio Ave
India
Amkar Perm
FC Strogino Moscow
FC Chernomorets Novorossiysk
Ipswich Town
Guizhou Hengfeng FC
Khimik Dzerzhinsk
FC Tver
Krasava Odintsovo
FC Avangard Kursk
Barnsley FC
Duzcespor
FC Kairat Moscow
Al Sareeh
Al Yarmouk
FC Shinnik Yaroslavl        
FC Zvezda Ryazan
Saturn Ramenskoye
FC Khimki-M
Santos FC SP
Calcio Catania
Colchester United
Strumska Slava
Yenisey 2 Krasnoyarsk
SC Farense U23
Audax Italiano
FC Znamya Noginsk
FC Maan
Znamya Truda
FC Chertanovo Moscú
FC Kaluga
Zenit Penza
Al Draih
AL Nahdha
FK Zeljeznicar Sarajevo
Nepal
Hapoel Nir Ramat Hasharon FC
Hapoel Ramat Gan Givatayim FC
Hapoel Petah Tikva FC
Fredrikstad FK 2
Sogndal 2
Aalesund 2
Rosenborg BK 2
MKS Arka Gdynia
Viking 2
BK Forward
FK Eik Toensberg 871
Odds BK 2
Valerenga IF 2
CD Malacateco
HB Koege
IFK Varnamo
Osters IF
Turkgucu Munchen
Al Jeel
Royal Excel Mouscron
RFC Seraing
FC Botosani
Lierse Kempenzonen
KV Kortrijk
KVC Westerlo
Cercle Brugge
CA Paranaense PR
Birmingham City
Ferrocarril Midland
Central Córdoba de Rosario
BFC Siofok
CD Santamarina Tandil
CA Excursionistas
Agropecuario Argentino
KMSK Deinze
K Beerschot VA
Coleraine FC
Uruguay Montevideo FC
US Palermo
FC Villefranche-Beaujolais
Fulgencio Yegros
CSD Rangers
UD Almería
Palmeiras SP
Nacional de Madeira
Leones FC
Gimnasia Y Esgrima Mendoza
Talleres de Córdoba
CA Cerro
Queretaro FC
Tacuary Asunción
Coritiba PR
CA Banfield
Defensor Sporting
Cruz Azul
Club Leon
Manta FC
Curico Unido
Estudiantes Río Cuarto
Atlas FC
Club Santos Laguna
```

Comment: I didn't look network. This is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://www.teapuesto.pe/sport/daily-matches'
session = HTMLSession()
html_text = session.get(url)
html_text.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.html.html, 'lxml')
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: thank you for sharing but the thing is, there is a error showing in html_text.html.render()

Comment: Did you install request-html?

Comment: requests is a default python library, you dont have to install it, you just have to import it in your script like "import requests"

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Comment: @y.y `requests` in NOT default python library and you have to install it. But if you install `requests_html` then probably it will install `requests` too.

Comment: @furas i can not remember that I had to install it via pip on my mac, thought its defo a default library

Comment: @y.y try `pip install --upgrade requests` and it should install the newest version - so it is NOT default library. You can't do this with `urllib` because it is default library. If I'm no wrong `pip` may use `requests` so it could install it. OR some other module may use `requests` and it could install it automatically as `dependence`. BTW: you can alos find `requests` on page [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) (which show all modules avaliable in `pip`) but you can't find `urllib` on this page (there are modules with name similar to `urllib` - like `urllib3` or `urllib-3`, etc.)